# Twitter API: unique id and email address?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm integrating Twitter as a way for users to register on my site. Questions:

1. Does Twitter return the email address of the user?
2. In the following response: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/account/verify_credentials - is `id` the way for me to uniquely identify the user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but user's email is not avaliable  through twitter api.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. What about the id?

Comment: here [https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/account/verify_credentials] in line 14

Comment: hi, that's the exact same link I put. Is `id` what I should be using?